# How do I set the swipe function to "trash" rather than "archive" for my Gmail inbox in iOS 7?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, gmail, trash

I have two IMAP email accounts on my iPhone 5S running iOS7.

With the iCloud account, I can perform an easy *swipe left* gesture and select "trash" for individual emails (see first image, black boxes added for redaction):

[image: iCloud account]

However, using the same gesture in my Gmail inbox, I'm presented with "Archive" rather than "Trash" (see screen capture below). From here I have to hit "More > Move Message... > Trash" to delete it.

[image: Gmail Account]

**How do I set either my Gmail preferences or iPhone Mail preferences to mimic the behavior of the iCloud account's "Trash" option when I swipe?**

Comment: Why was this question downvoted...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calenders -> GMail -> Account -> Advance

Move discarded messages into: Deleted Mailbox

Comment: I additionally had to change "Archive Mailbox" to "On the Server" vs "On my iPhone" for some reason, but this answered my question and all is working as desired. Thanks.

Comment: np, my pleasure :)